# Error when searching database with value from radio button

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list for “Gender”.
The choices are: No preference, Male, Female.
I have a search page and a user can search by these options. I create  a session variable for Gender, `Session["Gender"]`. The attribute in the database table is GenderType and it is varchar(8). 
On the Asp side this is the code behind to grab the value from the search page:

```
  if (rdogender.SelectedItem.Text == "Male")
  {
      Session["Gender"] = ((string)"Male");
  }
  if (rdogender.SelectedValue == "Female")
  {
      Session["Gender"] = "Female"; 
  }
```

When I search I keep gettting the error below. I have also tried the following:

```
 Session["Gender"] = ((String)rdogender.SelectedValue);
 Session["Specialty"] = (string)ddlSpecialty.SelectedValue;
 Session["Gender"] = ((String)rdogender.SelectedValue);
```

No matter how it is coded, I still get the error below. Does anyone know how to fix this?

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Male' to data
>   type int.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion
>   failed when converting the varchar value 'Male' to data type int.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

```
  Stack Trace: 

  [SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the                varchar value 'Male' to data type int.]
```

Comment: What is your database field type for gender?

Comment: if you are on same page you can use ViewState rather than Session for search. Please elaborate more on query front and your datatype of the field in database you are using

Comment: According to the error message, your database field type is not varchar(8). Please double check.

Comment: i think your database field is int check it.

Comment: I double checked the database and it is varchar. Should I drop this attribute a recreate it?                                         There is a search page where the user enters the criteria. Then the results are displayed on a search results page that has a grid view.

Answer (score 0):

hi you are using selected value use SelectedItem.Text.

```
  if (rdogender.SelectedItem.Text == "Male")
  {
      Session["Gender"] = ((string)"Male");
  }
  if (rdogender.SelectedItem.Text == "Female")
  {
      Session["Gender"] = "Female"; 
  }
```

for male you are check selecteditem.text and for Female you are check SelectedValue.

Comment: I have tried both to fix the issue. I just did SelectedItem.Text for both male and female but I still get the same error.

Comment: databse field is sure varchar(8)?put your axpx page code here.

Comment: There is a lot commented out. Trying to get this working before cleaning up the code. But here it is:

Comment: your datatype is int check first.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

Comment: using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class SearchResource : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Remove("ResourceID");
        Session.Remove("Name");
        Session.Remove("City");
        Session.Remove("State");
        Session.Remove("County");
        Session.Remove("Specialty");
        Session.Remove("ZipCode");
        Session.Remove("Language");
        Session.Remove("Gender");
    }

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
    }
    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear out all text fields and reset drop down boxes to start values
        txtResourceID.Text = null;
        txtName.Text = null;
        txtCity.Text = null;
        ddlState.SelectedIndex = 30;
        ddlCounty.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlSpecialty.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtZipCode.Text = null;

Comment: ckbLanguage.SelectedIndex = 0;
        rdogender.SelectedIndex = 0;
        //  ddlWithin.SelectedIndex = 0;
        chkPopulation.SelectedIndex = 0;

        txtResourceID.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtResourceID.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtCity.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        lblError.Visible = false;



    }

Comment: protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        txtResourceID.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtResourceID.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        txtCity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtCity.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        lblError.Visible = false;

Comment: if (txtResourceID.Text != String.Empty)
        {


            Session["ResourceID"] = int.Parse(txtResourceID.Text);
            Session["Name"] = null;
            Session["City"] = null;
            Session["State"] = null;
            Session["County"] = null;
            Session["Specialty"] = null;
            Session["ZipCode"] = null;
            Session["Language"] = null;
            Session["Gender"] = null;

Comment: foreach (ListItem li in ckbLanguage.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
            {

                if (li.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                {
                    Session["" + li.Text + ""] = null;


                }
            }

            //Session["Population"] = null;

Comment: foreach (ListItem lis in chkPopulation.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
            {
                if (lis.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                {
                    Session["" + lis.Text + ""] = null;

                }
            }


            Session["Insurance"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx");
            
        }


        else if (txtName.Text != String.Empty)
        {

Comment: Session["ResourceID"] = null;
            Session["Name"] = txtName.Text.Trim();
            Session["City"] = null;
            Session["State"] = null;
            Session["County"] = null;
            Session["Specialty"] = null;
            Session["ZipCode"] = null;
            Session["Language"] = null;
            Session["Gender"] = null;

Comment: foreach (ListItem li in ckbLanguage.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
            {

                if (li.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                {
                    Session["" + li.Text + ""] = null;


                }
            }

            //Session["Population"] = null;

Comment: foreach (ListItem lis in chkPopulation.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
            {
                if (lis.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                {
                    Session["" + lis.Text + ""] = null;

                }
            }

Comment: Session["Insurance"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx");

        }

Comment: else if (txtCity.Text != String.Empty)
            
                             
                {
                    Session["City"] = txtCity.Text.Trim();
                   
                   
                }

Comment: if (ddlState.SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    Session["State"] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
                  
                }

Comment: if (ddlCounty.SelectedValue != null)
                   
                {
                    Session["County"] = ddlCounty.SelectedValue;
                   
                }

Comment: else if (ddlSpecialty.SelectedValue != null)
                {
                    Session["Specialty"] = (string)ddlSpecialty.SelectedValue;
                }
               

              
                if (txtZipCode.Text != "")
                {
                    Session["Zip"] = txtZipCode.Text;
                }

Comment: foreach (ListItem li in ckbLanguage.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
                {
                    if (li.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                    {
                        Session["" + li.Text + ""] = (int)1;
                       // MessageBox.Show("Session " + li.Text + " is: " + Convert.ToString(Session["" + li.Text + ""]));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["" + li.Text + ""] = (int)0;
                       
                    }
                }

Comment: if (rdogender.SelectedItem.Text == "Male")
                
                {
                    Session["Gender"] = ((string)"Male");
                }
                 if (rdogender.SelectedItem.Text == "Female")
                    
                {
                    Session["Gender"] = "Female"; 
                
                }

Comment: foreach (ListItem list in chkPopulation.Items)  //This will run through the check boxes in the checkbox list
                {
                    if (list.Selected)  //If the checkbox is checked,
                    {
                        Session["" + list.Text + ""] = (int)1;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session["" + list.Text + ""] = (int)0;
                       
                    }
                }

Comment: if (ddlInsurance.SelectedValue == "Select A Value")
                {
                   // Session["Insurance"] = ddlInsurance.SelectedValue;
                    Session["Insurance"] = null;

                }
                else
                {
                   // Session["Insurance"] = null;
                    Session["Insurance"] = ddlInsurance.SelectedValue;
                }

Comment: Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx");
            }
        }